# Oracle query: get all records in a table where the record's unique UID exists in its blob field

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to come up with a query where I can get all records in a table where the record's unique UID exists in its blob field.

All I've been able to come up with so far is to check this on an individual basis given the UID.  For example, if the UID = 3210, I can use this query and if it returns a row, I know the UID exists in the blob:

select * from my_table where 
   dbms_lob.instr(blob_field, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('3210')) > 0 and my_table_uid = 3210

Since the table has over a million rows, obviously this is a horrible solution.  Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured out that I need to put the dbms_lob() call in the select rather than in the where clause and then check if it > 0